# How to diagnose email sending issue Sendgrid: Activity says processed but not received

Tags: sendgrid

I had a proyect inactive for about a year. The email sending functionality was working fine. I reopened it and tested but now the email sending does not work. When I login I can see that the email has been "Received by SendGrid" and "Processed" successfuly but the next step is frozen at "Received by gmail.com: Pending"

My reputation is fine, so I have not been baned. The email is fine, as I tried manually sending an email from and to the same address and I received successfuly.

Is there somwhere where I can see more information about what can be happening?
The first test is pending since yesterday. I don't think and email can take so long to process. I also made a test with a non-existing email and it threw the error immediately (row 2 on the image) so the recipient email is not the problem.

Any help is much appreciated .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to SendGrid support, this means that the account was blocked for inactivity, so it wont be able to send emails. Its necessary to create a new account. You can create a new account using the same email

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka8Ag.jpg)

According to them, this deactivation cannot be undone, so the only solution is to create a new account. Apparently this is done for security purposes. I quote:

> Unfortunately, we won't be able to reactivate your old account.
> We recommend logging in to your account at least once a month to prevent account deactivation for inactivity in the future.
> Please note that suspension is also needed for security purposes.

So unfortunately it seems that your only solution is to create a new account and set everything up again

Comment: Really? I cannot believe they don't allow to reactivate. Thank you